# SQL Sever 2012 - generating scripts - Save to File = Not Run

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am creating scripts of a SQL Server 2012 database because I cannot backup the database to a local drive. I understand how to create the script but at the end of the process the application seems to get stuck at the Save to file = Not Run.

The database is a huge database, but it appears that not much data is being written to the drive.

Comment: i am not writing any code to generate these script I am using the sql server default to generate the script. I am however creating scripts for tables, stored procedures and views individually.

Comment: What application are you using? SSMS? Where are you attempting to save the scripts to? What are you attempting to script out?

Comment: This error still happens in 2019, with SQL Server Management Studio v17.9. Unbelievable...

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a bug in SQL Server 11.0.6020 tools.
There is no trace in event log or server log, the script generator wizard just stops at the last step (which is writing the script to the destination, which can be a file or a new script window - either remains in status "not run" forever, with "Cancel" as the only possible user action).

Some experimenting showed that it indeed depends on script size.
I was not able to reproduce the problem on any lower or newer version of Microsoft SQL Server.

The solution is annoying: click yourself through the wizard multiple times, first scripting only database definition in parts:

- datatypes, functions and tables
- then only views, and
- then only procedures

You can later concatenate the three resulting files if that is a requirement.
This approach will not help if any of the three parts alone is bigger than the (unknown) treshold. Eventually, script the data, selecting only smaller sets of tables for each run.

Comment: Yes it's damn annoying. Administration on SQL Server in general can be fustrating even to  simple tasks like these . This was why people in our company dropped it. It didn't worth the money. We moved to PostgreSQL and everbody is happy ever since.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in one of the comments on the original post, this is still an issue with SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1  To work around it, I was able to use the "Single file per object" option.  I definitely would have preferred a single file, but at least it worked this way.  There was still a bit of a delay between the time that the status for all database objects showed Completed and the time that the "Save to file" line item changed from "Not Run" to Completed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio version 18.6. I wanted to export to a query in a new window:

[image]

But it resulted in it saying "Not run":

[image]

And a few seconds later, it said "Error":

[image]

Instead, what worked, was to save the result to a script file:

[image]

And here is the successful result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012, I managed to bypass this problem by just closing the SSMS and starting the process of generate scripts again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a UI issue only, for me the file was created even when it was still shown as 'Not Run' and it contained every exported db object. After a while, it changed into 'Success'